# What is the syntax for parameter pack expansion with alignas?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm trying to expand a parameter pack in an alignment specifier.  I can't get the syntax right.  Here's a simple example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Ts>
struct C
{
    using Tuple_Type = std::tuple <Ts...>;

    void f()
    {
        uint8_t i1;
        uint8_t i2 alignas (2);
        uint8_t i3 alignas (typename std::tuple_element<0, Tuple_Type>::type);
        uint8_t i4 alignas (Ts...);
    }
};

//template class C <>;  // not compatible with i3 declaration above
template class C <uint64_t>;
```

This fails to compile with gcc 4.8.3:

```
foo.cpp: In member function 'void C<Ts>::f()':
foo.cpp:14:31: error: expected ')' before '...' token
         uint8_t i4 alignas (Ts...);
                               ^
foo.cpp:14:31: error: expected ')' before '...' token
foo.cpp:14:31: error: expected initializer before '...' token
```

The C++ standard ([dcl.align]) says "An *alignment-specifier* with an ellipsis is a pack expansion", so it seems like it should be possible to do what I want.

I've been unable to find an example of this kind of parameter pack expansion, and my search for a possible bug in gcc didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [bug c++/59012](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59012) in GCC, which was fixed in GCC 5.2.  Your example [compiles fine](http://goo.gl/ZcIPzg) with Clang 3.5.1.

It's interesting to note that GCC properly complains about the parameter pack if you omit the ellipses entirely:

```
14 : error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
uint8_t i4 alignas(Ts);
^
```

You're not going to be able to (easily) get this to work with GCC 4.8.x; it's just too stupid.  With GCC 4.9 and later, however, you can use the following idea, which I adapted from [ecatmur's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31813440/1830736) to use a constexpr `max`.

```
template<int...>
struct maxInts {};

template<int A, int B, int... Cs>
struct maxInts<A, B, Cs...> {
    const static int value = A > B ? maxInts<A, Cs...>::value : maxInts<B, Cs...>::value;
};

template<int A, int B>
struct maxInts<A, B> {
    const static int value = A > B ? A : B;
};

template<int A>
struct maxInts<A> {
    const static int value = A;
};
```

This just lets you get the maximum of any number of integers at compile time, as in:

```
const int x = maxInts<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>::value; // x == 5
```

Now your troublesome `alignas` looks like this:

```
uint8_t i4 alignas(maxInts<alignof(Ts)...>::value);
```

[Here's a working example.](http://goo.gl/A4HucP)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct; gcc only implements pack expansion within an alignment-specifier since 5.2.0. Here's the bug: **[59012 - alignas does not support parameter pack expansions](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59012)**.

You could try using `alignas (std::aligned_union_t<1, Ts...>)`, but unfortunately gcc only implements [`aligned_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union) since 5.1.0, so it's only slightly better.

If you want to work with older compilers, you'll have to write your own constexpr `max` function (since older versions of gcc don't implement `constexpr max(std::initializer_list<T>)` either) and compute the maximum alignment yourself, as `alignas(max({alignof(T)...}))`.

Comment: `std::max({alignof(T)...})`

Comment: @Columbo yes, but older versions of gcc don't implement `constexpr max(std::initializer_list<T>)` either.

Comment: @Columbo thanks, although that won't work in C++11 mode.